# Remove one-sample capture delay in .keydown()

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

For special reasons I'm using JQuery's keydown() event to filter keystrokes in a hidden input field. The value of the input field then gets copied to a visible div. The problem is for some reason the keys I press are copied to the div the next time I press a key, meaning the input is delayed by one cycle.

I've tried keyup() and this one does work, however I don't like the behaviour of having the value update when the key is released. How could I make the update instant while keeping keydown() ?

```js
var wordInput = '';

$('#input').keydown(function(event) {
    var keycode = event.which;
    switch(keycode) {
     // Enter key
     case 13:  
      console.log('Submit');
     // Space key
        case 32:  
         console.log('Space disabled');
         break;
     // Backspace
     case 8:
            // Subscract the last char
            wordInput = wordInput.substr(0, wordInput.length - 1);
      break;
     // Any other key
  default:  
   // If char limit not exceeded
   if (wordInput.length < 20) {
                wordInput += $('#input').val(); // Add the typed letter
            }             
    }
    // Update the word displayed
    $('#story-input').html(wordInput);
    // Clear the  input
    $('#input').val('');
});
```

Check out the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mqbxqLp7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the event is fired first and processed by your code, then the character is added to the input field. This makes the `$('#input').val()` return previously entered character.

You could use `String.fromCharCode(event.which)`, but this will not distinct different case, you'll have to parse event object for modifier keys and turn the character to correct case.

---

Alternative solution would be to use `.keydown` to handle special keys like you do now and `.keypress` to handle character keys. The reason for this is `.keypress` doesn't register some keys, for example backspace.

This combines "best of both worlds", it handles all events right away and you don't need to worry about parsing characters to use right case.

Use this code or take a look at (fixed) example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/mqbxqLp7/2/).

```
$('#input').keydown(function(event) {
    var prevent = true;
    switch(event.which) {
        // Enter key
        case 13:    
            console.log('Submit');
        // Space key
        case 32:    
            console.log('Space disabled');
            break;
        // Backspace
        case 8:
            // Subscript the last char
            wordInput = wordInput.substr(0, wordInput.length - 1);
            break;
        // Any other key
        default:    
            prevent = false;
    }
    // Update the word displayed
    $('#story-input').html(wordInput);
    // Clear the  input
    $('#input').val('');

    // Stop event propagation, keypress will not be executed
    if(prevent)
        event.stopPropagation();
});

$('#input').keypress(function(event) {
    if (wordInput.length < 20) {
        wordInput += String.fromCharCode(event.which); // Add the typed letter
    }
    $('#story-input').html(wordInput);
});
```

Comment: A comment to alternative solution: only drawback to is that `.keypress` registers only one character while holding down the key, but I imagine you used `.keydown` only for backspace, so you can hold it down and delete multiple characters with a single key press. I don't think `.keydown` for regular keys would have any use for regular keys since users press each key when typing, they (typically) don't hold it down.

Comment: Nice! stopPropagation is what I needed. So, to get it clear, why would keypress happen after? Is it simply because it's below keydown code?

Comment: No, it's because how keyboard events work. Follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Auto-repeat_handling) to read more about keyboard events. Note that this doesn't apply only for jquery or javascript, it's how keyboard events work system wide. It's `keydown` -> `keypress` -> `keyup` and it's handled by operating system, programs or programming languages can't override this event sequence. By the way, if this answer helped you, please accept it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought the sequence depends on the OS. Thanks for your help!

Comment: PROBLEM now is keypress isn't supported in mobile chrome :(

Answer (score 0):

For this instance, jQuery's [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) hook may be more appropriate. This way, it will only fire after the key has been released, and the value is in the input box. This should make it much smoother, eliminating the next keypress triggering the previous push to the value, instead it being triggered by the end of the current keypress. (Demo in the included snippet.)

```js
var wordInput = '';

$('#input').keyup(function(event) {
    var keycode = event.which;
    switch(keycode) {
     // Enter key
     case 13:  
      console.log('Submit');
     // Space key
        case 32:  
         console.log('Space disabled');
         break;
     // Backspace
     case 8:
            // Subscract the last char
            wordInput = wordInput.substr(0, wordInput.length - 1);
      break;
     // Any other key
  default:  
   // If char limit not exceeded
   if (wordInput.length < 20) {
                wordInput += $('#input').val(); // Add the typed letter
            }             
    }
    // Update the word displayed
    $('#story-input').html(wordInput);
    // Clear the  input
    $('#input').val('');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="story-input">text</div>
<input type="text" id="input" style="opacity: 1">
```

However, note that a user can bypass the length requirement by holding down a single character, so it may be wise to check the sum of the length of `wordInput` with the length of the value of `#input`.